# Find function in Excel VBA only refers to newly created sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have been racking my brain on a bug whereby VBA seems to be using the wrong sheet within a Find function. For purposes such as printing the name of the sheet and values within cells, VBA refers to the sheet I expect. But for the Find function, it reverts to the most recently created sheet and I cannot force a reference to any other sheet. Below is an example that illustrates the problem. The lastRow variable gets assigned based on the Find function from the newly created sheet (three row) whereas the sht variable refers to the five row sheet.

```
Option Explicit
Dim wb As Workbook

Sub start()
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Call make5RowSheet
    Call make3RowSheet
    Call CountRows5RowSheet
End Sub

Sub CountRows5RowSheet()
    Dim thing As Variant
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    
    For Each thing In wb.Worksheets
        If LCase(thing.Name) = LCase("five rows") Then Set sht = thing
    Next thing
    
    With sht
        lastRow = Cells.Find(What:="*", _
            After:=.Range("A1"), _   '!!! .range here should refer to five row sheet, but lastRow gets set to 3
            LookAt:=xlPart, _
            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
            MatchCase:=False).Row
    End With

    Debug.Print "sheet name: " & sht.Name                       'prints "five rows" as expected
    Debug.Print "Cell(3,3) value: " & sht.Cells(3, 1).Value     'blank, as expected
    Debug.Print "cell(5,5) value: " & sht.Cells(5, 1).Value     'prints "foo", as expected
    Debug.Print "last Row: " & lastRow                          'prints 3, which is puzzling

End Sub



Sub make5RowSheet()

    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Set sht = wb.Worksheets.Add
    
    sht.Name = "five rows"
    sht.Cells(5, 1) = "foo"
    
End Sub


Sub make3RowSheet()

    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Set sht = wb.Worksheets.Add
    
    sht.Name = "three rows"
    sht.Cells(3, 1).Value = "foo"
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here

```
With sht
    lastRow = Cells.Find(What:="*", _
```

`Cells` is not tied to `sht` so it refers to the ActiveSheet

```
With sht
    lastRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
```

should fix things

Answer (score 0):

Your `Cells.Find` will be executed on whatever sheet is active.
In your case, the last sheet that was created is `three rows`.

So to avoid this hassle, make sure you `Activate` the right sheet right before you `Find`.

```
sht.Activate   ' move from (three rows) to (five rows)

With sht
        lastRow = Cells.Find(What:="*", _
            After:=.Range("A1"), _   '!!! .range here should refer to five row sheet, but lastRow gets set to 3
            LookAt:=xlPart, _
            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
            MatchCase:=False).Row
    End With
```